# How to achieve pre-created stack of screens in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, routes

Suppose I have a main page, and three other page, like PageA, PageB, PageC.

I have a button in main page, by clicking the button, I can go to PageC.

Now, I want a behaviour to go to PageC, but when I press back button, I want to go back to PageB first then PageA then to the main page.

Scenario is pretty much like this:

[Button in main page] `onClick` -> Go to PageC.

Now In PageC.

[Back Button in pageC/Back] `onClick` -> pop to PageB -> [Back Button in pageB/Back] `onClick` -> pop to PageA -> [Back Button in pageA/Back] `onClick` -> pop to main page.

Be noted, PageB, PageA, PageC, they are independent, if I go to PageC from another page,I don't want the same behavior, just only from a special event.

Just [this](https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/build-complex-navigation-stack-with-flutter-eaea732c6e6a) scenario, difference is, I don't want it in the starting point!

I am using `onGenerateRoute` procedure.

Comment: I think you can't push if you don't have screens in stack. May be WillPopScope will work to handle back button. When you click back button in screen C, just push to Screen B. pushNamedAndRemoveUntil will work if I'm right.

Comment: in general, you can't go back to a page that you didn't push to the stack. you can't go back to pageB if you haven't come from that page. however, using a declarative routing like go_router, you can program the back button to go to whatever page you wish.